# Can I build secondary language resources in a separate build step?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

We have 259 projects in our standard build.  We have our own system for concurrent building that is very efficient.  At one point, however, we have only a single project building, which is a large resource project with string tables that most other projects depend on.  This project takes a full minute to build.  It consists mostly of resx files that are string translations for all of the languages we support.

If I just build the base language, the project builds in 8 seconds and all of the dependencies can build that much sooner.  What I need to do is build the base dll and then create a separate build step to build the language resources - these are separate dlls in subfolders named for the culture and language.  My first thought was to create 2 project files.

My current solution is to separate the other languages into their own project.  I use the same namespace and then rename the resources dlls in all of the subfolders after the build finishes.  It also creates a meaningless standard dll that I have to delete.  It works and my build is fast now, but it's not elegant by any means and it's complicated from a training and maintenance standpoint.  Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: I assume you're using MSBuild?

Comment: @Amy, yes, we use msbuild, but we call it independently for each project.